# How to implement refresh jwt in nest socket server?

Tags: sockets, jwt, nestjs, refresh-token

I'm using a nest js hybrid between an API rest and a socket server.

**Which is the best practice to refresh access tokens without disconnect the socket connection?**

I mean, the first attempt to connect with the server, the server will validate an access_token which it'll receive by `client.handshake.auth.token`. But then when this token expires how can I get a new access_token and how can I validate it without disconnect?

To get a new access_token I thought 2 solutions when the client receive the expired jwt error:

Sending the refresh token by an argument in an emitted event from the client. Like:
`socket.emit('refresh-jwt-token', refresh_token);`

Or maybe sending an http request to a refresh endpoint with the refresh_token in the Authorization header in order to get a new access_token.

But then how can I use the new access_token? I also thought in sending the new access_token as a parameter of an emit event like: `socket.emit('random-event', acccess_token, random_param);` but it seems to be a bad way to do this.

Comment: You can validate the token only at the connection time. Then on subsequent events instead of validating the token, you could ignore the token altogether. If you need user info from the token, you could call `decode` function instead of validating and get the user info.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ErangaHeshan, I'll try to implement it like you say. I suppose that i have to add more checks in the client side to decide if close the connection or not, for example if the tokens expire, the user sign out or the app change to a background state (its a mobile app).